# Angular 5 change elements with change of route

Tags: angular

I have an array with users who have some properties. When user changes the route it should show the only those who have some specific property which is placed in url.
For now I can only display all the users everywhere and component doesn't seem to change when `id` is changed.

I've tried this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('departmentId');
    this.employeeService.getEmployees()
      .subscribe(emps => this.employees = emps);

    this.employees = this.employees.map(emp => {
      if (emp.departmentId === id) { return emp; }
    });
}
```

Comment: You want to use filter(), not map(). And you need to filter the employees every time the departmentId changes, not just once, when the component is initialized. So you need to subscribe to the route.paramap observable instead of just looking at the snapshot.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit?

Comment: What don't you understand? Have you done a bit of research, like rading the documentation of the Array.map() and Array.filter() methods, to understand what they do? Read the documentation of ActivatedRoute, to see what route.paramMap is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to `route.params` to handle changes.
Then note that `getEmployees()` is asynchronus. So when you try to filter, the variable `this.employees` may not have been initialized. You could filter inside the subscribe.

Do something like that:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        const id = +params['departmentId'];
        this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(emps => 
            this.employees = emps.filter(emp => emp.departmentId === id)
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: Console throws an error `Property 'departmentId' does not exist on type 'Employee[]'.`, thought it exists in the interface.

Comment: And this one `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'params.get['departmentId']')`

Comment: It's `params['departmentId']`, not `params.get['departmentId']`. I've also update my answer for the first issue. Should be fine now.

Comment: I've managed to get `id` from route with your help, but now it doesn't seem to filter. It throws an error that `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Employee[]>'`. I've added import from `rxjs`, but it causes new error which is in first comment

Comment: You're not supposed to filter on the Observable, but on the array. See my answer again. She's been updated.

Comment: I misplaced filter. It was on direct response from service instead of being inside of subscribe.