# Route from app component side bar to component with parameter

Tags: angular

I have an app.component with a sidebar. When the app.component is loaded I dynamically build the sidemenu from data from a backend. When clicking one of the dynamically generated links in the side menu, I want to load a component and build content based on that parameter. My first thought was to use routerLink:

app.component:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" [routerLink]="['/assets',menuItem]">{{menuItem}}</div>
</div>
```

And then subscribe on those parameters in the constructor of the component. However I realized the constructor is not called when clicking each link (properly because Angular know the component is allready loaded).

What is the right approach do do something like that? I am new to Angular so feel free add snippets, or link to sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 change elements with change of route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354845/angular-5-change-elements-with-change-of-route)

Comment: Thanks, it actually got me a working sample. But I am more looking for some guidance whether this is the correct approach for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your routes have to be registered in app.module.ts file (so you can access menuItem value in YourComponent):

   ```
   Router.forRoot(
       [
           { path: 'assets/:menuItem', component: YourComponent }
       ]
   )
   ```
2. Subscribe to event:

   ```
   constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private router: Router) {}

   ngOnInit() {
       this.sub = this.route
       .queryParams
       .subscribe(params => {
           params['menuItem'];
       });
   }
   ```